# Should I use inheritance or not?

Tags: java, oop

I have a class that contains:

- Header(class)
- a List of Details(class)

A detail can have 3 types, all different attributes. And they have 2 attributes in common, so I used inheritance.

The problem is that the code is getting harder and harder to maintain, especially when I have to get a detail in the List. I have to do stuff like:

```
if(detail instanceof DetailType1){
   something
}
else something
```

Is there an alternative? Any recommendation?

Appreciate in advance.

Edit:

```
List<String> values = new ArrayList<String>();

for (Detail detail : fFile.getDetails())
  {
    if (detail instanceof DetailType1)
    {
      values.add(fFile.getHeader().getEntity() + "-" + detail1.getType());
      values.add(((DetailType1) detail).getServiceReference());
      values.add(fFile.getHeader().getProcessedDate());
    }
    else if (detail instanceof DetailType3)
    {
      values.add(((DetailType3) detail).getClientCode());
      values.add(((DetailType3) detail).getMaxAmount().toString());
      values.add(((DetailType3) detail).getReference());
    }
    ...
  }
```

Comment: Can you share what kind of code is executed? Is that strictly related to specific DetailType class

Comment: A solution commonly used in situations like this is to put a virtual method in your Detail classes so that you can just call the method instead of checking the exact type of the instance.  Would this work in your case?

Comment: Using inheritance generally means you *don't* end up using `instanceof` (which you're quite right to identify as a problem). If you can describe the problemin more detail, show us the code where you think you need to use `instanceof`, we may be able to help. But we can't help with what's in the above at the moent.

Comment: Why do you need to use instanceof?

Comment: The point of polymorphism is so that you don't have to use `instanceof` that often and instead just call any given method on any `objectY` that inherits from `objectX`

Comment: I'd recommend using a method like `getDetails()` for all `DetailTypes` that returns the appropriate details that depend on the given `DetailType` (Done inside each `DetailType` class)

Then return a `List<Detail>` and loop through it, adding them all to `values`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general you were correct that instanceof is a bad smell--the way to fix it is through calling a method on an interface that is implemented by all the objects you were using "instanceof" on.

Here's how I see it in your case:

DetailType1 and 3 should implement the same interface with a method like:

```
addToValues(List<String> values){}
```

They each implement this interface differently, an example, DetailType1 should look something like this (You may have to pass in fFile as well):

```
 addToValues(List<String> values){
     values.add(fFile.getHeader().getEntity() + "-" + getType());
     values.add(getServiceReference());
     values.add(fFile.getHeader().getProcessedDate());
 }
```

The original loop from your code then becomes:

```
for(Detail detail : fFile.getDetails())
    detail.addToValues(values);
```